# How to update Azure database connected to Xamarin.Forms app with offline sync without App crashing?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, synchronization, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Xamarin Forms with Azure mobile service, and added a column into the table schema on Azure SQL database, then the mobile App crashed because the local store (SQLite) is different from the Azure database.

To solve that I removed current app, this will remove local database and installed new app version.

But I am wondering what the best approach is when you want to make changes in the azure database and release these changes.

How can you update both database and app without the user losing data or experiencing crashes?

Comment: You can update your local database when app launches. If it's offline at that time, load the data from your local database then update it when the app reconnect to the network.

Comment: Thanks, I know but it has not the problem.